# How can I find the commands for different keys in python with ctypes

Tags: python, keyboard, ctypes

I have a python program where I would like to use the keyboard using ctypes e.g `ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0, 0x0002, 0)`. Is there anywhere where I can find the events for all the different keys?

Comment: Yes. In the official docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event.

Comment: @CristiFati thank you, that was quite obvious now I think about it :)